¿Como le cambio el tamaño a un Chart en Visual Studio .Net?
En vb.net estoy usando la herramienta chart y al momento de córrelo el grafio me da mas pequeño y no se aprecia bien.

este es el codigo:
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Class Prueba

    Dim query1

    Private Sub Prueba_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ChartColumnas()
        'ChartNacionalidad()
        query1 = "select distinct sede from DatosTabla"
        CbSede.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        CbSede.DisplayMember = "SEDE"
        query1 = "select distinct NIVEL from DatosTabla"
        CbNivel.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        CbNivel.DisplayMember = "NIVEL"
        query1 = "select distinct CATEGORIA from DatosTabla"
        CbCategoria.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        CbCategoria.DisplayMember = "CATEGORIA"
        query1 = "select distinct PROGRAMA_EDUCATIVO from DatosTabla"
        CbPrograma.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        CbPrograma.DisplayMember = "PROGRAMA_EDUCATIVO"
        query1 = "select distinct ESTADO_NACIMIENTO from DatosTabla"
        CbEstadoNac.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        CbEstadoNac.DisplayMember = "ESTADO_NACIMIENTO"
        query1 = "select distinct ANIO from DatosTabla"
        cbAño.DataSource = Conexion.SelectQuery(query1)
        cbAño.DisplayMember = "ANIO"
    End Sub

    Sub ChartColumnas()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT EDAD, COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD_ALUMNOS FROM DatosTabla GROUP BY EDAD ORDER BY EDAD"
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = Conexion.SelectQuery(query)

        Dim chartArea1 As New ChartArea()
        ChartE.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1)

        Dim series1 As New Series()
        series1.Name = "Hombres"
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column

        For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
            series1.Points.AddXY(row("EDAD").ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(row("CANTIDAD_ALUMNOS")))
        Next

        Dim series2 As New Series()
        series2.Name = "Mujeres"
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column

        ChartE.Series.Add(series1)
        ChartE.Series.Add(series2)

        ChartE.Size = New Size(452, 178)
        ChartE.Location = New Point(34, 516)
        Me.Controls.Add(ChartE)
    End Sub

End Class


Estas definiendo un tamaño fijo,por esta razón no cambaría de tamaño:
ChartE.Size = New Size(452, 178)

Puedes hacer que la medida sea dinamica, cambiando el alto y ancho de esta forma:
...
    ChartE.Size = New Size(Me.Width - 50, Me.Height / 2)
    ChartE.Location = New Point(10, 10)
...

